# How to call a plugin from my .vimrc file?

Tags: function, vim, plugins, call

I am using a VIM plugin called [Goyo](https://github.com/junegunn/goyo.vim) (for writing markdown files). It is similar to Distraction Free mode in SublimeText. I want to create a write-mode in my `.vimrc` that I can toggle. This toggle will set various options on in write-mode, such as `set spell`, `set wrap` etc.

I have everything working here, except calling the `Goyo` function. How can I execute the Goyo plugin from within my ToggleWrite() function?

Here is my code:

```
" Write toggle switch
let b:write = "no"

function! ToggleWrite()
  if exists("b:write") && b:write == "yes"
    let b:write = "no"
    set nowrap
    set nolinebreak
    set textwidth=100
    set wrapmargin=0
    set nospell
    " ↓↓↓ I want to call this ↓↓↓
    ":Goyo
  else
    let b:write = "yes"
    set wrap
    set linebreak
    set textwidth=100
    set wrapmargin=0
    set spell
    " ↓↓↓ I want to call this ↓↓↓
    ":Goyo 60x100%
  endif
endfunction

" Set up the toggle sequence
nmap  <expr> ,w  ToggleWrite()
```

Comment: just `Goyo 60x100%` or `Goyo`?

Comment: That gave me a lot of errors when I tried that. Maybe it worked (called Goyo) but broke something else in the process.

Comment: Could you give the error output please?

Comment: E523: Not allowed here:   tab split
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function ToggleWrite[19]..goyo#execute[7]..<SNR>
100_goyo_on[87]..<SNR>100_init_pad:
line    1:
E523: Not allowed here: vertical topleft new
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function ToggleWrite[19]..goyo#execute[7]..<SNR>
100_goyo_on[87]..<SNR>100_init_pad:
line   13:
E523: Not allowed here: 0wincmd w
Press ENTER or type command to continue
..etc

Comment: Why did you add `<expr>` to your mapping? try `nmap ,w :call ToggleWrite()<cr>`

Comment: I was something I copied from another post somewhere that worked for something else. Your `nmap ,w :call ToggleWrite()<cr>` solution works for me. Thanks @tolenoyer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put my comment as an answer:

Your mapping uses `<expr>`, which is not right in your case. You should try this mapping instead:

```
nmap ,w :call ToggleWrite()<cr>
```

or

```
nmap <silent> ,w :call ToggleWrite()<cr>
```

`<expr>` lets you make "custom" mappings, depending on the return of a function. It's rarely used in common cases.